# Neo4j: Using Log Function in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, logarithm

I'm trying to implement a tf-idf transformation on my graph in neo4j, on a raw tie as co-occurence. To do that, I need to take the log of the number of nodes divided by the degree of a single node.

Is there a way to use take logarithms in cypher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, as of now support for mathematical functions is rather limited: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html

However you could file a feature request at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new.

Comment: Any suggestions for an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I just submitted a pull request: 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/869

Answer (score 1):

According to their cheat sheet it is now possible to calculate a `log(x)` or `log10(x)`:

http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/

Release 2.0.0 (the first supporting this) is out since some weeks now.